# Prove that $\sin{(\pi 2x)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (0.5-x))}\,\right)$ is an increasing function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Could anybody show that

$f(x)=\sin{(\pi 2x)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (0.5-x))}\,\right)$ is increasing on the interval $x\in[0, 0.25]$?

Of course, $\csc{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sin{(x)}}$.

Here is the graph of $f(x)=\sin{(\pi 2x)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (0.5-x))}\,\right)$.

Definitely increasing on $x\in[0, 0.25]$.

I want a mathematical proof.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The function can be written as
$$
f(x)=2(\sin(\pi x)+\cos(\pi x))=2\sqrt{2}\sin\Bigl(\pi x+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)
$$
and the conclusion follows from the fact that
$$
f'(x)=2\pi\sqrt{2}\cos\Bigl(\pi x+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr),
$$
which is positive for $0<x<1/4$.

Comment: $\sin y+\cos y=\sqrt2\sin(\frac\pi4+y),$ right; though it does not affect the answer much

Comment: how? We are interested in sign, not in magnitude of $f'(x),$ right?

Comment: we are talking at cross purposes. You have rectified, the mistake I was pointing out.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Now I understand. :) I'll remove also this comment soon.