# maximum of $f(x)=\sin{(\pi Ax)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (\frac{1}{A}-x))}\,\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let a function $f(x)$ be

$f(x)=\sin{(\pi Ax)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (\frac{1}{A}-x))}\,\right)$

where $A\geq 2$ is a positive integer and $\csc{(x)}=\frac{1}{\sin{(x)}}$.

I want to prove that on the interval $x\in[0, \frac{1}{2A}]$, $f(x)$ has its maximum at $x=\frac{1}{2A}$.

To prove that, I think we have two approaches.

First, prove it directly.

Second, prove that $f(x)$ is an increasing function  on the interval $x\in[0, \frac{1}{2A}]$.

When $A=2$, we are able to take the second approach thanks to a user named egreg.

[Prove that $\sin{(\pi 2x)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (0.5-x))}\,\right)$ is an increasing function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565447/prove-that-sin-pi-2x-left-csc-pi-x-csc-pi-0-5-x-right-is)

Now could anybody prove it generally?

I am not sure for any $A$, $f(x)$ is increasing on the interval $x\in[0, \frac{1}{2A}]$ (maybe true?), but strongly believe the maximum is $f(\frac{1}{2A})$.

The followings are graphs of $f(x)$ when $A=2, 3, 4$, respectively, where $\frac{1}{2A}=0.25, 0.1667, 0.125$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compute its derivative, and place $x=\dfrac1{2A}$. Notice that it equals $0$, meaning that $x=\dfrac1{2A}$ is among the extrema.

Comment: @Lucian Derivative being equal to $0$ does not mean that the point is among the extrema.

Comment: It is definitely among the local extrema. But you can't know whether it is THE highest or THE lowest until you actually compute its value, and compare it to those of the others. Unfortunately the equation $f'(x)=0$ is transcendental, so there really aren't any analytical ways of determining its other roots.

Comment: And if it's not among the local extrema, then it has to be an inflexion point. But you can prove that such is not the case by showing that $f''\left(\frac1{2A}\right)\neq0$.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a good chunk of the day and a bunch of headaches, but I was able to write an informal proof that that $f(x)=\sin{(\pi Ax)}\left(\,\csc{(\pi x)}+\csc{(\pi (\frac{1}{A}-x))}\,\right)$ has a maximum at $x=\frac{1}{2A}$ for any $A$ not only for integers >= 2, but for all reals $A < -1$ or $A > 1$.

The trick to proving this is we have to prove f(x)' is 0 and f(x)'' is negative.

Let $A$ be any number for the reals excluding 0 and

$f(x) = \sin( \pi A x)\csc(\pi x) + \sin(x \pi A)\csc( \pi(\frac{1}{A} - x))$.

Now we are going to derive f(x).

By deriving f(x), we get that:

$f'(x) =  A \pi \cos( \pi A x) \csc( \pi x) 
    - \pi\sin(\pi A x)\csc( \pi x)\cot(\pi x) 
    + \pi A\cos(\pi A x)\csc(\pi (\frac{1}{A}-x))
    +  \pi\sin(\pi Ax)\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{A}-x))\cot( \pi(\frac{1}{A}-x))$

Which reduces to:

$f'(x) =  \pi A \cos(\pi Ax)(\csc(\pi x) + \csc(\pi(\frac{1}{A} - x)) + \pi\sin(\pi Ax)(\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{A}-x))\cot(\pi(\frac{1}{A}-x) - \csc(\pi x)\cot(\pi x))$

Now we will substitute in $x = \frac{1}{2A}$ and get:

$f'(x) = \pi A \cos(\pi A(\frac{1}{2A}))(\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A})) + \csc(\pi(1/A - (\frac{1}{2A})) + \pi \sin(\pi A(\frac{1}{2A}))(\csc(\pi(1/A-(\frac{1}{2A})))\cot(\pi(1/A-(\frac{1}{2A})) - \csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}))\cot(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}))$

Which simplified looks like:
$f'(x) =  \pi A\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})(\csc(\frac{\pi}{2}) + \csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})) 
+ \pi \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})(\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A}) - \csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A}))$

Since $cos({\pi}{2})) = 0$ and $\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A}) - \csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A}) = 0$, we can further reduce the problem to:

$f'(x) =  \pi A(0)(\csc(\frac{\pi}{2}) + \csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})) + \pi \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})(0)$

So $f'(x) = 0$ for any real A that does not equal 0 so by definition, $\frac{1}{2A}$ is a critical point.

Now to prove that $x = \frac{1}{2A}$ is a maximum bigger headache.

In order to prove $x =\frac{1}{2A}$ is a maximum, we must prove $f(x)'' < 0$.

We now have to take the derivative of f(x)' and after much simplification, substituting  $x = \frac{1}{2A}$, and further simplifying, we get:

$f(x)'' = 2\pi^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})(\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})(-A^2+2\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A})^2+1)$

(I have all the work, it's just a lot to post.)

Now $2\pi^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})(\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})> 0$ for all reals except $A=0$,  so when $-A^2+2\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A})^2+1 < 0$ then $\frac{1}{2A}$ is a maximum.

Plugging in $-A^2+2\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A})^2+1$ into Wolfram Alpha, when $-1<=A<=1$ then $-A^2+2\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A})^2+1 > 0$ and when  $A < -1$ or $A > 1$ then $-A^2+2\cot(\frac{\pi}{2A})^2+1 < 0$.

So since f(x)'' is negative and f(x)' is 0, by definition $x=\frac{1}{2A}$ is a maximum for
all reals except for -1 <= A <= 1.

QED

(Thanks to Maple and Wolfram Alpha for helping derive and simplify the derivatives and checking the work.)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but notice that the statement you proved is "$f$ has a local maximum at $1/(2A)$". The question is about the global maximum on the interval $[0,1/A]$.

Comment: I can adjust the proof. All I need to show that f(x)' is positive on the interval [0,1/A2] which is just slightly different form the from the first half of my proof.

Comment: That would be good. Because in the current version, first half does more than is needed for $f'(1/(2A))=0$. The latter is a consequence of symmetry $f(x)=f(1/A-x)$. (Take derivative on both sides to get $f'(x)=-f'(1/A-x)$, and set $x=1/(2A)$.)

Comment: How do you know $x=1/2a$ is the only value that makes your derivative function zero?? the function could have other critical values as well.  your derivative function looks quite complicated, you can't judge about its zeros so easily.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very transparent answer, short and sweet.

$f(\frac{1}{2A}) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})[\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})+\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{A}-\frac{1}{2A}))]=2\csc(\frac{\pi}{2A})$

Now let let $0\le\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2A}$, then compute 
$$f(\frac{1}{2A}-\varepsilon)= \sin(\pi A(\frac{1}{2A} - \varepsilon))[\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}-\varepsilon)) + \csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}+\varepsilon))] =$$
Use two trig identities on the first term, to yield

$$=\cos(A \pi \varepsilon) [\csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}-\varepsilon)) + \csc(\pi(\frac{1}{2A}+\varepsilon))] $$
Now what can we say?  If $\varepsilon = 0$, we get back our orginal term.  So lets look at each individual bit.... after a moments thought, we see that each of the functions (the cosine is one function and the sum of the csc is the other) are each maximized when $\varepsilon=0$, because we are not maximizing them individually when $\varepsilon \neq 0$ we have that the full expression is not maximized for $\varepsilon \neq 0$ because in general we know (if you don't, you should)

$$\max\{f*g\} \le \max\{f\}*\max\{g\}$$

So maximizing the RHS of this inequality (in our case) gives our original function at $\frac{1}{2A}$ (this is easy to see), so it follows that this inequality is equality and we're done.  The LHS can get no better than the right hand side, which is obtained at $\varepsilon = 0$, so the max is realized the two coincide.

Comment: I think you lost the factor of $A$ in the first term (the one you apply trig identity to).

Comment: Okay... so I should have multiplied by $A$ rather than divide.... let me fix that. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, @PostNoBills do you understand the maximization inequality argument?  I think this is the kicker in my argument because unlike others I don't take derivatives, because this really isn't necessary.

Comment: Well... how do you show that the second term (sum of cosecants) is maximized at $\epsilon=0$, without using derivatives?

Comment: Do you mind if I post that part in the comments (for brevity?)

Comment: It looks to me like the most substantial part of the answer; everything else you posted is rather simple.

Comment: the second part is actually have its min at zero. when epsilon tends to 1/2A  the first csc tends to infinity.

Comment: Yes, but we aren't letting epsilon go to 1/2A (read the first line).  The quick answer is that locally around $\varepsilon=0$ the dominating feature of the function is in cosine, so locally this is what we have to look at.  A better answer will have to wait, I have somewhere to be at the moment.

Comment: cosecant is a continuous function on its domain it doesn't jump on $(0, \pi )$, the closer you get to $o$ or $\pi$ the cosecant function gets bigger and bigger unboundedly.